# Spring Data JPA valid flag for entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I was searching for such a feature, where I can annotate a boolean field with, for example, `@ValidFlag`;

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @CreatedDate
    Date creationDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    Date updateDate;

    @ValidFlag
    Boolean isActive = Boolean.TRUE;
}
```

So, for example when I insert an entity with this field value `false`, no repository get operation should fetch this entity, it can be though, in a way, as a *dirty flag*. It would be a very nice way to hide this extra column check for every get operation I have for all entities extending this base entity.

If not supported natively (it looks like that), can you think of a way to handle this via some custom addition of logic onto Hibernate/JPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at how to implement soft delete with Hibernate.
That could work for your case too.

Add @Where clause on the Entity to exclude inactive entities from fetching:

```
@Where(clause = "isActive = true")
```

There are two great articles about that:

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-soft-delete-with-hibernate/
https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/implement-soft-delete-hibernate/

Comment: Did you add the @Where to the your BaseEntity?

Comment: I assume that you are using Hibernate > 5.1 Please read the article carefully : https://vladmihalcea.com/2017/03/08/the-best-way-to-soft-delete-with-hibernate/ you have to provide a @Loader for the EntityManger.find method